# Experiencing a Java error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, class, interface, enums

This is an example from my pdf  and it is not working at all for me when I test it:

```
static void changeMe(int prim) {
prim++;
static void changeMe(int[] obj) {
    obj[0]++;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 5;
    int[] j = {5};
    System.out.println("Before \ti = " + i + " \tj[0] = " + [0]);
    changeMe(i);
    changeMe(j);
    System.out.println("After \ti = " + i + " \tj[0] = " + j[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to close the body of your first `changeMe` method. It should be like:

```
static void changeMe(int prim) {
    prim++;
}

static void changeMe(int[] obj) {
    obj[0]++;
}
```

Furthermore, your first `System.out.println()` statement is also invalid, because you missed to specify the array you're referring the first element of:

```
System.out.println("Before \ti = " + i + " \tj[0] = " + j[0]); 
                                                        ^
```

Answer (score -1):

It's working only you have some small mistakes

```
static void changeMe(int prim) {
    prim++;
}
    static void changeMe(int[] obj) {
        obj[0]++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 5;
        int[] j = {5};
        System.out.println("Before \ti = " + i + " \tj[0] = " + j[0]);
        changeMe(i);
        changeMe(j);
        System.out.println("After \ti = " + i + " \tj[0] = " + j[0]);
    }
```